# bs() function not found

Tags: r, spline

I have installed and loaded the `splines2` package but when I call function `bs()` I receive an error message.  Any ideas how I can deal with this problem?  Thank you.

```
library("splines2", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
model <- lm(hwy ~ bs(displ, 4))
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "bs"
```

Comment: `bs` is an export from the splines package (which comes with R), not splines2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up. You should either use `splines::bs`, or `splines2::bSpline`.

I don't know why you use `splines2::bSpline` here (especially when you left `degree` unspecified which defaults to 3).  This function is largely based on `splines::bs`. It is an augmented function of `splines::bs`, where you can specify `degree = 0` to get a piecewise constant basis which is not allowed by `splines::bs`. But if `degree > 0`, it call `splines::bs` for all the rest.